# Default settings for pmset -g?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, defaults, maintenance

I remember changing some values to disable Deep sleep mode and hibernation a few months ago, and realised that my battery drains faster now. I just want to revert all settings to default. I changed some back such as `hibernationmode 3`, but not sure if I'm missing anything else.

Are these values normal for a 15" Retina Macbook Pro ? 
(I'd appreciate if anyone can crosscheck with theirs if you didn't tamper with the settings in `pmset -g` )

On power :

```
Active Profiles:
Battery Power       -1
AC Power        -1*
Currently in use:
 standbydelay         7200
 standby              1
 womp                 1
 halfdim              1
 hibernatefile        /var/vm/sleepimage
 darkwakes            1
 gpuswitch            2
 networkoversleep     0
 disksleep            0
 sleep                0
 autopoweroffdelay    14400
 hibernatemode        3
 autopoweroff         1
 ttyskeepawake        1
 displaysleep         60
 acwake               0
 lidwake              1
```

and on battery :

```
Battery Power       -1*
AC Power        -1
Currently in use:
 standbydelay         7200
 standby              1
 halfdim              1
 hibernatefile        /var/vm/sleepimage
 darkwakes            0
 gpuswitch            2
 disksleep            0
 sleep                180
 autopoweroffdelay    14400
 hibernatemode        3
 autopoweroff         1
 ttyskeepawake        1
 displaysleep         5
 acwake               0
 lidwake              1
```

Thanks

Answer (score 16):

One can use `pmset restoredefaults`, or in System Preferences > Energy Saver, click the Restore Defaults button.

If you want to see what changed, one can use `pmset -g custom` before and after restoring the defaults.

This worked for me, and is documented in `man pmset`, in macOS Mojave 10.14.5.

Answer (score 7):

`pmset -g` default settings vary by model.

Configuration profiles for AC/Battery/UPS differ on a model by model basis, but the numerical value assigned to the default profiles (rather than custom) respectively remains the same. Thus, you can always revert to pmset defaults by running the following command. I've appended `pmset -g` to the command so the current configuration is shown after running it:

```
pmset -c 2 -b 1 -u 1; pmset -g
```

You can confirm these are the defaults after running the command by opening

`System Preferences > Energy Saver` and seeing that the `"Restore to Defaults"` option is greyed out.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my configuration on AC:

```
Active Profiles:
Battery Power       -1
AC Power        -1*
Currently in use:
standbydelay         4200
standby              0
womp                 1
halfdim              1
hibernatefile        /var/vm/sleepimage
sms                  1
networkoversleep     0
disksleep            0
sleep                0
autopoweroffdelay    14400
hibernatemode        3
autopoweroff         1
ttyskeepawake        1
displaysleep         0
acwake               0
lidwake              1
```

…and on battery:

```
Active Profiles:
Battery Power       -1*
AC Power        -1
Currently in use:
standbydelay         4200
standby              0
halfdim              1
sms                  1
hibernatefile        /var/vm/sleepimage
disksleep            10
sleep                0
autopoweroffdelay    14400
hibernatemode        3
autopoweroff         1
ttyskeepawake        1
displaysleep         0
acwake               0
lidwake              1
```

Please note that I do have a MacBook Pro 13" (Non-retina), however that shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I've changed anything, but these are my settings:

I have a base model MacBook Pro with Retina display 15"

### AC:

```
Active Profiles:
Battery Power       -1
AC Power        -1*
Currently in use:
 standbydelay         4200
 standby              1
 womp                 1
 halfdim              1
 hibernatefile        /var/vm/sleepimage
 gpuswitch            2
 darkwakes            1
 networkoversleep     0
 disksleep            10
 sleep                15 (sleep prevented by backupd)
 autopoweroffdelay    14400
 hibernatemode        3
 autopoweroff         1
 ttyskeepawake        1
 displaysleep         15
 acwake               0
 lidwake              1
```

### Battery:

```
Active Profiles:
Battery Power       -1*
AC Power        -1
Currently in use:
 standbydelay         4200
 standby              1
 halfdim              1
 hibernatefile        /var/vm/sleepimage
 gpuswitch            2
 darkwakes            0
 disksleep            10
 sleep                10 (sleep prevented by backupd)
 autopoweroffdelay    14400
 hibernatemode        3
 autopoweroff         1
 ttyskeepawake        1
 displaysleep         5
 acwake               0
 lidwake              1
```

Answer (score 0):

Complete answer :

Some options like `Sleep` and `displaysleep`,  can be modified through `Power Saving` in the `System Preferences`panel.

Wikipedia isn't as complete as [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/pmset.1.html)

About the differences with Faiz's pmset :

- The rMPB has 2 GPU => GPU switch to save power or enhance performance
- The rMBP has no HDD => SMS (uses sensors in the HDD to protect the HDD) has no use
- `standbydelay` : delay before the data present in the RAM is copied into the HDD/SSD. Default is 4200 (seconds, about ~1h), so the computer shifts from sleep mode to deep sleep mode.
- WOMP for Wake : wake on ethernet magic packet. It's probably display when you are connected with an Ethernet.
- Darkwakes is some a kind sleep function presented at WWDC 2012 "Power Management"