# pmset -g: UPS Power -1; AC Power -1*

Tags: macos, mac, power-management

When issuing the command `pmset -g` in macOS (tested on El Capitan through High Sierra) the first two lines come up about the active UPS and AC profile:

```
Active Profiles:
UPS Power       -1
AC Power        -1*
```

What does the negative one (`-1`) refer to and what is the asterisk (`*`) denoting?

The question "[Default settings for pmset -g?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/85603/default-settings-for-pmset-g)" makes references these values, but doesn't explain what they mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is expected behavior.**

- The `-1` denotes that a "custom" profile is being used.
- The `*` denotes the profile currently in use.

So, from this we can see that there is a custom profile for both UPS and AC and that it is currently using the AC profile.

[image: macOS Energy Saver Preference Pane Defaults]

When using the macOS defaults as seen in Energy Saving Preference pane (above image), `pmset -g` gives the following:

```
Active Profiles:
UPS Power       -1
AC Power        2*
```

Now, the UPS is the only profile with a custom setting and the `2` denotes a predefined (default) setting for AC. Setting it back to a custom setting returns the profile value to `-1`.