# Mac goes unexpected to sleep

Tags: display, sleep-wake, catalina

After upgrading to MacOS Catalina (10.15.1) I have had troubles with the mac going to sleep mode when i close the lid while having external monitors connected. It used to be working like this:

What happens when the lid are closed?

1. When no external monitor are connected: Go to sleep.
2. When external monitor are connected: Display content on the external monitors.

Now it just goes into sleep mode no matter which setup is used.

Can you help getting the right configuration back?

Comment: Did you check whether you have enabled display driver or not from Security & Privacy -> Privacy -> Screen Recording

Comment: @Udhy It has an empty list. But can it be related?

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/18081/341892 - try this

Comment: @Udhy Okay, first step was to plug it into power... this solved the problem.

Comment: Unbelievable. Go to the effort to type up some stuff that deals with sleep, and you haven't even been bothered to plug it in.

Comment: @FiddleDeDee Well before the update it did not matter if the power was plugged in or not, so I did not realise this was a game changer.

Answer (score -2):

`pmset` is the terminal command to display all things sleep on OSX. `man pmset` shows you how to use the binary, `pmset -g` shows you the current settings.

It is possible to restore `pmset` to defaults by using the following commands (whilst sleep setting defaults differ from Mac to Mac, but apparently Apple have usefully made the numerical value that refers to the various profiles relatively the same.)

`sudo pmset -c 2 -b 1 -u 1; pmset -g`

[Sudo will require your password]

This last command from here: [Default settings for pmset -g?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/85603/default-settings-for-pmset-g)

Another suggestion is to reset PRAM and SMC:

> How to reset PRAM
>
> 1.Shut down your computer
>
> 2. Press the Power key
> 3. Immediately press Command + Option + P + R keys
> 4. Hold down the keys until your Mac reboots
> 5. Let go of the keys
>
> To reset SMC
>
> 1. Turn off your Mac
> 2. Hold down Control + Shift + Option and press power
> 3. Hold the buttons for 10-15 sec
> 4. Release the keys and restart your Mac

Comment: This does not answer the question at all...

Comment: No? I totally misunderstand what pmset does then. It governs all aspects of the system sleep.

Comment: How does this help with external displays connected and mac not going to sleep? Could you explain, please?

Comment: There will be a setting within pmset that will disable sleep mode entirely.